# ManagementObjectCollection returns null

Tags: c#, console-application

Hey i have some code to generate Hardware Id for identification and it have worked fine for several month but now without any changes it stopped working it stops at all of these

```
ManagementObjectCollection cpu_Collection = cpu.Get();
ManagementObjectCollection hdd_Collection = hdd.Get();
ManagementObjectCollection bios_Collection = bios.Get();
```

Can anyone help me fix it this is all of my code to get the hardware id

```
    //public static string test = ReturnHardwareID().ToString();
    private static async Task<string> ReturnHardwareID()
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        byte[] hashedBytes;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher cpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection cpu_Collection = cpu.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpu_Collection)
            {
                sb.Append(obj["ProcessorId"].ToString().Substring(0, 4));
                break;
            }

            ManagementObjectSearcher hdd = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
            ManagementObjectCollection hdd_Collection = hdd.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in hdd_Collection)
            {
                sb.Append(obj["Model"].ToString().Substring(0, 4));
                break;
            }

            ManagementObjectSearcher bios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
            ManagementObjectCollection bios_Collection = bios.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in bios_Collection)
            {
                sb.Append(obj["Version"].ToString().Substring(0, 4));
                break;
            }
        });
        Task.WaitAll(task);
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        hashedBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
        return await Task.FromResult(Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes).Substring(25));
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the code that you have provided is not what's causing the problem here. Could it be that the names/references of `Win32_Processor`, `Win32_DiskDrive` and `Win32_BIOS` have been changed?

Comment: Or access to the data changed? Or the server migrated to a different (virtual) location?

Comment: @AstridE. hmm maybe it's just weird that I haven't updated anything the code is the exact same as the last time I used it and my visual studio haven't been updated

Comment: @Stefan I don't think that would be what happened since its on my PC and not on a server

Comment: Have you tried to run it with administrator rights?

Comment: Yea it dosnt work